# C# TextBox Autocomplete (Winforms) key events and customization?

Tags: winforms, autocomplete

I was wondering if it is possible to catch key events for auto-complete list. For example instead of Enter key press for auto-complete use lets say Tab key. Also is it possible to change the colors and add background image for the auto-complete pop-up list? Currently I have my own implementation which is a separate window(form) with a list-box, which works OK, but Id really like to use .net's auto-complete if it can do what I need.

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WinForms's autocomplete is based on [Windows Shell's autocomplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776884(VS.85).aspx), so you can use the same interface. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762479(v=VS.85).aspx) are the options of the component. However I am afraid the customization you want is not there.